# unable to connect to remote MYSQL DB using Spring MVC, c3p0

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, mariadb, c3p0

I have a spring mvc project and connecting to Maria DB 10.11.0-MariaDB. I am able to connect to remote DB using mysql workbench, But not using spring mvc and c3p0. I am sure about the user name ,password,port and IP, as i am able to connect through the mysql work bench

Below are my DAO and pom xml configurations.

```
<bean id="Master" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close"> 
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/> 
    <property   name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://<DBIP>:3306/master_db"/> 
    <property name="user" value="xxxxxx"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxxxxxx"/>
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="2"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="3600"/>
      <!--   <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="30"/>-->
    <property name="numHelperThreads" value="6"/> 
</bean>
```

```
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Core utilities used by other modules. Define this if you use Spring 
            Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Expression Language (depends on spring-core) Define this if you use 
            Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core) Define 
            this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, 
            spring-beans) Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, 
            spring-beans) This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection 
            Container and is generally always defined -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, 
            Quartz, and Freemarker integration Define this if you need any of these integrations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-aop, spring-context) Define this if you use Spring Transactions or 
            DAO Exception Hierarchy (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, 
            spring-tx) Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, 
            and iBatis. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx) 
            Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*) -->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.20</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, 
            JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context) Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and 
            Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context) 
            Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another 
            web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet 
            Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet 
            Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and 
            TestNG This artifact is generally always defined with a 'test' scope for 
            the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20141113</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.13</version>
        </dependency> 
         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.6</version>
            </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>myapp</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
                    <server>tomcat7</server>
                    <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                     <warSourceDirectory>WebContent/WEB-INF</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <!-- <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <show>private</show>
                    <nohelp>true</nohelp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${findbugs.version}</version>
                <configuration>

                    <!-- Enables analysis which takes more memory but finds more bugs. If 
                        you run out of memory, changes the value of the effort element to 'Low'. -->

                    <effort>Max</effort>

                    <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                    <!-- Reports all bugs (other values are medium and max) -->
                    <threshold>max</threshold>
                    <!-- Produces XML report -->
                    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                    <!-- Configures the directory in which the XML report is created -->
                    <findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/findbugs</findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${findbugs.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

I am getting below exception:

```
18:28:04,626 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:435 - Executing SQL query [SELECT * FROM client`]
18:28:04,972  INFO AbstractPoolBackedDataSource:462 - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1hgeknaat1k2sq9317m1swv|a737736, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hgeknaat1k2sq9317m1swv|a737736, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 1, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://xx.xxx.xx.xx:3306/master_db, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 3600, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 100, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 2, numHelperThreads -> 6, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
18:29:00,596 DEBUG SqlUtils:99 - Converting Throwable to SQLException...
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.


detailed exception :
13:47:07,221 DEBUG BasicResourcePool:289 - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@b3937 config: [start -> 3; min -> 3; max -> 15; inc -> 3; num_acq_attempts -> 30; acq_attempt_delay -> 1000; check_idle_resources_delay -> 0; mox_resource_age -> 0; max_idle_time -> 0; excess_max_idle_time -> 0; destroy_unreturned_resc_time -> 0; expiration_enforcement_delay -> 0; break_on_acquisition_failure -> false; debug_store_checkout_exceptions -> false]
13:47:07,222  INFO AbstractPoolBackedDataSource:462 - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1hgekoiat1piitjos02ot4|2d7d25e2, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hgekoiat1piitjos02ot4|2d7d25e2, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://xx.xxx.xx.xx:3306/master_db, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 15, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
13:47:07,223 DEBUG BasicResourcePool:538 - acquire test -- pool size: 0; target_pool_size: 3; desired target? 1
13:47:07,224 DEBUG BasicResourcePool:1291 - awaitAvailable(): [unknown]
13:47:07,224 DEBUG BasicResourcePool:1644 - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@b3937 [managed: 0, unused: 0, excluded: 0]
13:47:08,532 DEBUG BasicResourcePool:1831 - An exception occurred while acquiring a poolable resource. Will retry.
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping(ConnectionImpl.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3590)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:346)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:563)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.resultSetToMap(Util.java:508)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping(ConnectionImpl.java:1004)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: If you are logging at INFO, you ouught to have seen one Exception stack trace (preceded by "An exception occurred while acquiring a poolable resource. Will retry.") before the CannotAcquireResourceException was thrown. If you log loggers under "com.mchange.v2.resourcepool" at DEBUG levels (or FINE or TRACE), you'll see an Exception stack trace for every failed attempt to connect. You may get more info from that.

Comment: @Steve Walman this is the exception :
17:11:25,288 DEBUG BasicResourcePool:1831 - An exception occurred while acquiring a poolable resource. Will retry.
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)

Comment: Not the most informative exception, that the MySQL driver provoked a NullPointerException while trying to put together and SQLException. The SQLException might have been more informative. The NPE is a bug in the driver, you might see if there’s a more recent JDBC driver you might upgrade to.

Comment: You are using an old version of the mysql drivers, upgrade, the fact that you use `${spring.version}` and a hardcode `5.3.20` makes me think that you are also mixing versions of Spring, use the version tag for that hardcoded version as well.

Comment: @SteveWaldman : I have added complete exception in the edit and I am using 8.0.29 JDBC driver

Comment: @M.Deinum : Thanks for poiniting it out, I have changed it to ${spring.version} and using 8.0.29 mysql JDBC driver, still no luck

Comment: Judging from the error that is something that is "wrong" with your schema/database as it tries to parse the result (probably the metadata) for which it returns something `null` which isn't allowed in a `TreeSet` (which is what C3P0 probably uses. I would however to ditch C3P0 and move to something like HikariCP (better performance and still being worked on). Not that it would solve the issue I think as it appears to occur in the driver.

Comment: @M.Deinum : Thanks for your input, however, when i move the war to the server where mysql is installed and change the jdbc url from IP to localhost it works. But when i try same war outside of the server and try to connect with IP address it shows above exception.

Comment: Can you even access the server from your machine and is that the correct one or is MySQL even listening on the remote network adapter?

Comment: @M.Deinum, I am able to connect to mysql server from my machine using mysql work bench with mysql server IP

Comment: You can connect what fails is parsing the properties obtained from the MySQL server upon connecting. What happens is that the command `SHOW COLLATION` is executed and the result is parsed, however one of those values or keys is `null`. Execute the command from the workbench and see what happens. Could be that you aren't allowed to execute it remotely and only locally.

Comment: (I don't think c3p0 isn't doing anything with a `TreeMap` here. This error is literally occurring at the moment it calls of c3p0 calling `driver().connect( jdbcUrl, overrideProps(username, password) )`, where `overrideProps(...)` is a `java.util.Properties` object. The `ResultSet` containing the `null` is something internal to the driver. @M.Deinum's suggestion of an unexpected `null` in `SHOW COLLATION` sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1** : Remove these codes, let C3P0 default values to test first. Then you update with the correct values

```
<property name="initialPoolSize" value="1"/>
<property name="maxPoolSize" value="100"/>
<property name="minPoolSize" value="2"/>
<property name="maxIdleTime" value="3600"/>
```

**Solution 2** : You copy/paste this

> **mysql://xx.xxx.xx.xx:3306/price_check_v2_master_db**

in your Exception and you get this in your code

> **jdbc:mysql://:3306/master_db**

Different DB names : price_check_v2_master_db VS master_db. Maybe that's where the problem comes from

Comment: Hi @zaarour, I have corrected the DB names, that was copy /paste error from side. I'll remove c3p0 properties and update you.

Comment: I have removed below properties of c3p0, still same exception

```<property name="initialPoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="2"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="3600"/>